# Seems like $S$-units equation in algebraic function fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb F_q$ be a algebraic function field ($q=p^f$), $S$ be a finite set of places of $K$, $O_S$ be the ring of regular functions of $K$ outside $S$ and $a,v\in O^\times_S$, $v\notin\overline{\mathbb F_p}$. 
The question: Consider an infinite set $I$ of $\mathbb N$ and $T=\{v^{p^i}\mid i\in I\}$. Is it possible that for all $x\ne y\in T$, $x+y+a\in O^\times_S$.

Comment: Sure there can. Take, for example, $m=n$ and $a = 1$. You have $2v^{p^n}+1 = (2v+1)^{p^n}$, which is an $S$-unit for all $n$ if $2v+1 \neq 0$ and $S$ is taken large enough that it contains all zeros and poles of $2v+1$. You should make your question more precise.

Comment: Thanks. With your answer, I see that I wrote is not what I thought. So I edit my question.